# polygon UIView to fire an event

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiscrollview

I need something like that:
An **image map** (I think it will have to be done with an `UIView` of some sort) which is an image (a special map) with some areas (polygons) which should call an event when touched... How to make a poligon-"overlay" for images which fire an event?
The **image map** mentioned above and an `UITableView` in a `UIScrollView` - but I think this shouldn't be that hard...? Should look like this afterwards.

```
-------------------------- UIScrollView top
 +-----------------------+
 +    polygon UIView     +
 +-----------------------+
 +-----------------------+
 +      UITableView      +
 +-----------------------+
-------------------------- UIScrollView bottom
```

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd create a subclass of UIView (e.g. `DOMImageMapView`), with a list of `CGPathRef` or `UIBezierPath` instances associated with it.

In `DOMImageMapView`'s `drawRect:` implementation, you would draw the image, and then iterate through each path instance and fill it using `CGContextFillPath()` or `-[UIBezierPath fill]`.

For hit tests, you would implement `touchesEnded:withEvent:` (or similar), and test each path via `CGPathContainsPoint()` or `-[UIBezierPath containsPoint:]`. If one of the paths returns `YES`, call a delegate method like `imageMapView:didSelectArea:`.

Your `UITableViewController` (or `UIViewController` with a `UITableView` in it) would create the `DOMImageMapView` and set itself as the `delegate`. When an area is tapped, the controller will receive the callback and can handle the event appropriately.

Comment: Thanks so far. I think I know how to implement that. Will report it when done. May take some time though ;-).